# SceneKit shows only partly a large rotated SCNPlane

Tags: rotation, scenekit

I try to create a large SCNPlane to cover whole screen. The test code is bellow in which a red box (size 1x1x1) is in the middle of a blue plane (size 200 x200). They all are in the central point (0, 0, 0) and the camera is only +5 from that point.

When the plane node faces to the camera (with a large angle), it works well (figure 1) and both left and right sides could cover whole left and right sides of the screen. However when I rotate the plane to a small angle (with the camera), only a small part is shown. In figure 2, the left side of the plane comes closer to the camera. That left side should be wide enough (side of 100) to cover all left side of the screen but it is not. Increasing the size of the plane to 10 times (to 2000) did not help.

Any idea about the problem and solution? Thanks

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
    scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    scnView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
    scnView.allowsCameraControl = true

    scnView.scene = SCNScene()
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    scnView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 5)


    let theBox = SCNBox(width: 1, height: 1, length: 1, chamferRadius: 0)
    theBox.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red

    let theBoxNode = SCNNode(geometry: theBox)
    theBoxNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, 0)
    scnView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(theBoxNode)

    let plane = SCNPlane(width: 200, height: 200)
    plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue
    let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
    scnView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode)
}
```

[image: Blue plane face to camera]

[image: Blue plane rotated to a small angle to camera. Left side is closer but it does not cover whole left side of the screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to check your camera's [`zNear`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scncamera/1436592-znear) property to ensure that the plane isn't clipped. You can find an explanation of clipping planes [here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/3ds-max/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/3DSMax/files/GUID-C2E55F9A-4F78-4D48-B5C5-1127AA5FBF2C-htm.html).

Comment: Wow, thanks. That is basic knowledge I missed. It works.
For anyone has the same problem, try to add: cameraNode.camera?.zNear = 0.001 (zNear doest not accept zero)